# Compiling and running java with external libraries in dockerfile

Tags: java, json, docker, dockerfile

I am struggling to compile and run a java file using docker. I have the file structure:

```
./Repo/
   Dockerfile
   ./libs/
      org.json.jar
   ./out/
      Program.class
   ./src/
      Program.java
```

My Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

COPY /src /src/
COPY /out /out/
COPY /libs /libs/

RUN javac ..
CMD java ..
```

I want to be able to compile the files in src and output them in out whilst using the external libs
The only way I have managed to do this is to first CD into /src/ and run the following:

```
javac -d ../out -cp ../libs/org.json.jar Program.java
```

But surely there is a way to do this from the directory that the Dockerfile is in like?

```
javac -d /out -cp /libs/org.json.jar /out/Program.java
```

The next issue is the CMD required to run the above program. I'm not sure how to write this.

Or should I copy the json lib to the out folder where the compiled program is and run the following CMD:

```
java -cp "org.json.jar;" Server
```

Comment: You don't need src Java files in the container... Why not just use Maven or Gradle to build the container with library dependencies?

Comment: So compile them to out and COPY just the OUT and LIBS folder? I can't use Gradle or Maven unfortunately. How would I still run the Program with a CMD in docker though? If the external .jar is in a different directory or should I COPY the .jar into the out?

Comment: You can't even use the Maven container to build a project, for example? Sorry, I didn't see that you run javac within the container

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Maven, I need to use javac and java within the dockerfile

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure I understand the restriction. How would anyone know the difference between `FROM maven` and `FROM java` as long as the container runs?

Comment: Sorry, I think I also got a bit confused myself, the FROM maven would replace the first line in the docker file I'm guessing? If that is the case how would maven change the docker file to do what I'm trying to achieve which is make the java program run when I use docker-compose up program

Comment: It would be able to build a JAR of many Java files and download the libraries for you. Then you would run the JAR https://aboullaite.me/multi-stage-docker-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compile the Program.java file from the /out path instead of the src, which is probably why it wasn't working.

Try this

```
RUN javac -d /out -cp /libs/*.jar /src/Program.java
```

Then you'll not need to copy out folder because it'll be created when the container is built. When you run `docker build`, things should compile

---

Otherwise trying to run javac outside the container, /out and /src don't exist on your source machine, so you must use relative paths in the command, then copy the out folder **only** in the Dockerfile and remove the javac usage (and switch to using the JRE image)

Comment: running that in the Repo directory gives me the error:
javac: file not found: \src\Program.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: You don't need to run it from the repo. It runs when the container builds... I'm confused what the ultimate goal is, but it seems like you already have Java installed locally, so why do you need to do javac in the container?

Comment: Ah, I will test this tomorrow when I get a chance to, I don't have docker at home installed. I was using the building of the docker image to compile the java. If I want to execute the program when I use docker-compose up program what CMD would I use to run the java with the .jar too

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["java"] CMD ["-cp", "/libs/*.jar:/out", "Program"]`

Comment: Would you be able to explain what the entry point key word does in this context please?

Comment: It is prepended to any arguments of the CMD. You can refer to the Docker documentation for more information